# Calculation expansion factor of $x ^ n - x - 1$

Tags: ntru

I'm trying to calculate the expansion factor for a polynomial of the form $x ^ n - x - 1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Where did you exactly fail to find the expansion factor?

Comment: what is the expansion factor? to make your question self-contained for a general audience

Comment: (The appendix of) [this work](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~vlyubash/papers/generalknapsackfull.pdf) can help.